# Android HttpURLConnection подгружается только часть ответа на запрос

Tags: java, android, http

Есть обычный код.

Проблема в том что результат я получаю не полный. 
А только какую то часть, то есть даж не часть, а первые 4066 символов.
Изменил польностью код. Проблема та же самая, IOException вроде бы не вызываются

```
private class GetContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bSFiRdwiSq?indent=2");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

            Log.d("Result:", resultJson);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Вот результат

```js
D/RESULT:: [  {    "guid": "fdaefcc1-6469-4e3a-9d03-722f8de768d9",     "index": 0,     "favoriteFruit": "banana",     "latitude": 52.644930000000002,     "company": "DECRATEX",     "email": "jodiecollier@decratex.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "esse",       "tempor",       "fugiat",       "labore",       "eu",       "aliquip",       "fugiat"    ],     "registered": "2015-06-07T09:21:48 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "blue",     "phone": "+1 (870) 541-3015",     "address": "503 Rugby Road, Defiance, Alaska, 2923",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Melton Reese"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Sara Gilbert"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Nicholson Weber"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Fugiat Lorem mollit in pariatur incididunt est cupidatat veniam sit officia. Dolor dolor velit ex fugiat dolore officia enim quis in pariatur do ea. Ipsum cillum duis aliquip ut occaecat qui sint est aliqua consequat reprehenderit non. Velit pariatur aute voluptate minim in deserunt amet duis laborum laborum amet. Fugiat nostrud culpa ipsum Lorem proident pariatur aliqua fugiat culpa. Et aliquip magna exercitation ipsum aute voluptate. Dolore magna sint duis ipsum eu consectetur.\r\n",     "balance": "$3,384.03",     "name": "Jodie Collier",     "gender": "female",     "age": 27,     "greeting": "Hello, Jodie Collier! You have 3 unread messages.",     "longitude": 173.90763799999999,     "_id": "58046a786230071a551569b9"  },   {    "guid": "badaf4d6-54fa-46e3-8a6d-6b6997483b00",     "index": 1,     "favoriteFruit": "strawberry",     "latitude": 39.709885,     "company": "DRAGBOT",     "email": "alstonmays@dragbot.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "elit",       "ea",       "ipsum",       "velit",       "amet",       "laborum",       "duis"    ],     "registered": "2016-06-01T05:06:26 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "green",     "phone": "+1 (911) 423-3011",     "address": "248 Forbell Street, Mathews, Vermont, 4994",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Liza Day"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Catherine Palmer"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Beryl Conway"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Proident id fugiat pariatur et incididunt commodo est irure in duis ullamco veniam est magna. Id enim qui commodo exercitation labore adipisicing excepteur adipisicing dolor veniam. Qui quis minim commodo mollit est sit.\r\n",     "balance": "$1,375.60",     "name": "Alston Mays",     "gender": "male",     "age": 33,     "greeting": "Hello, Alston Mays! You have 10 unread messages.",     "longitude": -67.445130000000006,     "_id": "58046a78a50c13da27ab0d11"  },   {    "guid": "e328c11c-f948-42a6-aede-179ec44a7873",     "index": 2,     "favoriteFruit": "apple",     "latitude": 17.807843999999999,     "company": "INSOURCE",     "email": "cassandramcintyre@insource.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "et",       "anim",       "dolor",       "magna",       "quis",       "occaecat",       "dolor"    ],     "registered": "2015-09-11T03:36:24 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "blue",     "phone": "+1 (865) 558-2301",     "address": "189 Cranberry Street, Riverton, Arkansas, 5369",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Whitley Howe"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Roseann Perez"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Sasha Richard"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Consequat adipisicing ut dolor in. Id enim consectetur qui incididunt non amet laboris. Veniam amet dolore proident est proident dolor sunt nulla est quis veniam commodo anim. Ut exercitation excepteur enim quis et ea veniam non laboris duis. Dolore cillum commodo dolore reprehenderit aliqua labore.\r\n",     "balance": "$3,678.92",     "name": "Cassandra Mcintyre",     "gender": "female",     "age": 29,     "greeting": "Hello, Cassandra Mcintyre! You have 8 unread messages.",     "longitude": 93.
```

Весь лог

```js
10/17 16:38:54: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "lutmobile.com.chatforclash/lutmobile.com.chatforclash.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 20027 on device Nexus_5X_API_22 [emulator-5554]
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is lutmobile.com.chatforclash, real application class is null.
W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/lutmobile.com.chatforclash/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/lutmobile.com.chatforclash/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex) with checksum 0x115b7e55 in OatFile /data/data/lutmobile.com.chatforclash/cache/slice-slice_2-classes.dex
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9683
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 323582673
V/FA: Collection enabled
V/FA: App package, google app id: lutmobile.com.chatforclash, 1:289646024129:android:828d73aeecfbef22
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
        adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode lutmobile.com.chatforclash
V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9452280
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1378725
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                  [ 10-17 10:38:54.848 20027:20027 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f2075546740, tid 20027
D/Atlas: Validating map...
W/FA: Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}

      [ 10-17 10:38:54.920 20027:20072 D/         ]
      HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f207840cec0, tid 20072
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f207851a540, error=EGL_SUCCESS
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1382044
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1382080
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f2075546dc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f20755b2800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f20784bc660
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f20755925c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
V/RenderScript: 0x7f207863d000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
D/Result:: [  {    "guid": "fdaefcc1-6469-4e3a-9d03-722f8de768d9",     "index": 0,     "favoriteFruit": "banana",     "latitude": 52.644930000000002,     "company": "DECRATEX",     "email": "jodiecollier@decratex.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "esse",       "tempor",       "fugiat",       "labore",       "eu",       "aliquip",       "fugiat"    ],     "registered": "2015-06-07T09:21:48 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "blue",     "phone": "+1 (870) 541-3015",     "address": "503 Rugby Road, Defiance, Alaska, 2923",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Melton Reese"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Sara Gilbert"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Nicholson Weber"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Fugiat Lorem mollit in pariatur incididunt est cupidatat veniam sit officia. Dolor dolor velit ex fugiat dolore officia enim quis in pariatur do ea. Ipsum cillum duis aliquip ut occaecat qui sint est aliqua consequat reprehenderit non. Velit pariatur aute voluptate minim in deserunt amet duis laborum laborum amet. Fugiat nostrud culpa ipsum Lorem proident pariatur aliqua fugiat culpa. Et aliquip magna exercitation ipsum aute voluptate. Dolore magna sint duis ipsum eu consectetur.\r\n",     "balance": "$3,384.03",     "name": "Jodie Collier",     "gender": "female",     "age": 27,     "greeting": "Hello, Jodie Collier! You have 3 unread messages.",     "longitude": 173.90763799999999,     "_id": "58046a786230071a551569b9"  },   {    "guid": "badaf4d6-54fa-46e3-8a6d-6b6997483b00",     "index": 1,     "favoriteFruit": "strawberry",     "latitude": 39.709885,     "company": "DRAGBOT",     "email": "alstonmays@dragbot.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "elit",       "ea",       "ipsum",       "velit",       "amet",       "laborum",       "duis"    ],     "registered": "2016-06-01T05:06:26 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "green",     "phone": "+1 (911) 423-3011",     "address": "248 Forbell Street, Mathews, Vermont, 4994",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Liza Day"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Catherine Palmer"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Beryl Conway"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Proident id fugiat pariatur et incididunt commodo est irure in duis ullamco veniam est magna. Id enim qui commodo exercitation labore adipisicing excepteur adipisicing dolor veniam. Qui quis minim commodo mollit est sit.\r\n",     "balance": "$1,375.60",     "name": "Alston Mays",     "gender": "male",     "age": 33,     "greeting": "Hello, Alston Mays! You have 10 unread messages.",     "longitude": -67.445130000000006,     "_id": "58046a78a50c13da27ab0d11"  },   {    "guid": "e328c11c-f948-42a6-aede-179ec44a7873",     "index": 2,     "favoriteFruit": "apple",     "latitude": 17.807843999999999,     "company": "INSOURCE",     "email": "cassandramcintyre@insource.com",     "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",     "tags": [      "et",       "anim",       "dolor",       "magna",       "quis",       "occaecat",       "dolor"    ],     "registered": "2015-09-11T03:36:24 -06:00",     "eyeColor": "blue",     "phone": "+1 (865) 558-2301",     "address": "189 Cranberry Street, Riverton, Arkansas, 5369",     "friends": [      {        "id": 0,         "name": "Whitley Howe"      },       {        "id": 1,         "name": "Roseann Perez"      },       {        "id": 2,         "name": "Sasha Richard"      }    ],     "isActive": false,     "about": "Consequat adipisicing ut dolor in. Id enim consectetur qui incididunt non amet laboris. Veniam amet dolore proident est proident dolor sunt nulla est quis veniam commodo anim. Ut exercitation excepteur enim quis et ea veniam non laboris duis. Dolore cillum commodo dolore reprehenderit aliqua labore.\r\n",     "balance": "$3,678.92",     "name": "Cassandra Mcintyre",     "gender": "female",     "age": 29,     "greeting": "Hello, Cassandra Mcintyre! You have 8 unread messages.",     "longitude": 93.
W/FA: Tasks have been queued for a long time
```

Comment: `int len = 500` вы сами говорите, чтобы 500 символов скачал. в вашем ответе как раз 500 символов

Comment: Кстати да, и это тоже пытался. Как определить длину запроса? просто если указывать ну NNNN то приходить на подобии ответ 
"company": "DRAGBOT", 
                                                                         "email": "alstonmays@dragbot.com", 
                                                                         "pict����������������������������������������������������������������������

Comment: ну или как то указать что бы грузил весь контент.
Код скопирован с оф. документации

Comment: уберитие лимит в 500 символов, прочитайте все из потока и закройте InputStream сразу же после этого

Comment: Дико неудобно. Я только изучаю поэтому реализацию вашего совета, не особо понимаю. Перехожу из php :( Если не трудно, не могли бы ткнуть пальцем

Comment: Все сделал. Но теперь возникла проблема из за которой я и собственно говоря пишу этот вопрос. 

Изменил обработку данных

<code>
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null){
            total.append(line);
        }

        return new String(total);
</code>
 
Но теперь приходит только первые 4066 символов

Answer (score 2):

прроблема в том, что вы сами говорите, чтобы 500 символов скачал `int len = 500`
в вашем ответе как раз 500 символов

Пример чтения потока.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
    reader.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо за код, как выше написал, уже таким же образом и сделал. И собственно говоря возникла ситуация, из за которой возникла вся проблема. Этот код грузит только первые 4066 символов. Остальных нету.

Comment: @user3331078 очень странно, обновите вопрос и приложите новый output ваш

Comment: Обновил. Я тут впервые, поэтому паралельно пытаюсь разобратся как тут работать ))

Comment: насчет 4066 символов, у вас IOException не вызывается? может соединение разрывается ? проверьте это, пожалуйста

Comment: Изменил код, на более оптимизированный, в логах после вывода результата только это 

`W/FA: Tasks have been queued for a long time`

Comment: @Injection прикрепите весь лог. там точно нет исключений ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46917/discussion-between-injection-and-senior-automator).